# Running Jersey on Heroku - App Error

Tags: heroku

I am trying to run a Jersey Server on heroku.

This works fine locally. and I have tested it. [1].

When I run it on heroku I bind to the port given by the PORT environment variable. I tried with localhost, 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0. But when I try to access the application by heroku given url I get an application error. It prints [3].

Can anyone help me on the please?

[1] INFO: Jersey app started with WADL available at http://127.0.0.1:8080/HelloWorldExample.svc/application.wadl

[2] INFO: Jersey app started with WADL available at http://0.0.0.0:40243/HelloWorldExample.svc/application.wadl

[3] 2018-02-15T08:04:20.300885+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/HelloWorldExample.svc/application.wadl" host=absiodata.herokuapp.com request_id=abbf8aa1-bd10-4dff-b36e-eeba2fb30528 fwd="81.246.22.26" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http

Comment: Didn't find a way forward. However implemented web app (servlet) using Olingo and it worked on heroku. Finally found a solution for the problem.